# Ignore extra property from entity while getting data from DB using EF Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using EF Core. I want to extract data from the database using a stored procedure and EF Core. I am getting error for those property whose are not returned from DB. How can I fix this?

Entity:

```
public class CustomOverview
{
    public int A{ get; set; }
    public int? B{ get; set; }
    public int? C{ get; set; }
    public int? D{ get; set; }
}
```

Repository code

```
public async Task<CustomOverview> GetMyData()
{
    return  _dbContext.CustomOverviews.FromSqlInterpolated($"exec spr_myStoredProcedure).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

My stored procedure returns data for Column A, Column B.

When I run the code, I get this exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The required column 'C' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.

How can I resolve it? There is many solution where they suggest to remove property or use `[NotMapped]` attribute before the property. But my requirement is I need those property for different stored procedure. So I couldn't remove them.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new class that matches the stored procedure return results.

or

2. Use traditional data reader to read the stored procedure results into your existing class.

or

3. Add columns C and D to the stored procedure results, using Null values if appropriate.